# low memory warning when saving files on blackberry

Tags: memory, blackberry, java-me

I want to save many files on **Sdcard**. When I save these files on folder I get a warning that the memory is low

> the device memory is too low - please close the following items

and the application crashed.
The problem that I can put the folder manually and I didn't get problem of memory but in the pplication it show it even there is free space on Sdcard.
This the method that I used to save files.

```
public static void saveWebContentCache(String save_name, String url) {

    FileConnection fconn = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(
                NetWorkConfig.webfolder + save_name,
                Connector.READ_WRITE);
        if (!fconn.exists()) {
            fconn.create();
            outputStream = fconn.openOutputStream();

            outputStream.write(getByte(url));

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Status.show("ko !");
    } finally {// Close the connections
        try {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                outputStream.close();
                outputStream = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        try {
            if (fconn != null) {
                fconn.close();
                fconn = null;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the size of a file the app fails on?

Comment: I don't have a static file. Every file has a size. But the size of the folder is about 1.8 Mo

Comment: I guess "Mo" is MByte?

Answer (score 3):

As for me, this line looks suspicious:

```
outputStream.write(getByte(url));
```

This is because such implementation implies you have to create/hold in RAM the entire byte array before writing it to file's `OutputStream`.

Instead, you could combine reading by small chunks from the `InputSteam` of an http connection and writing the chunks to file's `OutputStream`. Something like this:

```
void copyData(InputStream source, OutputStream destination) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = source.read(buf)) > 0) {
        destination.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    destination.flush();
}
```

Comment: getByte(url) is the data byte[] that I get it from url to write it in files

Comment: I'm not copy data from file to another file. I get data from url then I save it into file

Comment: yes, I understand that, however I am 100% sure your `getByte(url)` uses `InputStream` to get the `byte[]` from the http connection.

Comment: yes, when I used your method I get runtime exception. This is my input stream how I get it and the output like I made in the example HttpConnection conn = getHttpConnection(url);
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
InputStream input = conn.openInputStream();

Comment: what kind of runtime exception? what is the error message? at what line of code? this is rather odd. it should work.

Comment: JVM Error 104 Uncaught:RuntimeException there is no line where the exception and when I debug it crash   while ((len = input.read(buf)) > 0)

Comment: So it crashes on reading a small chunk from InputStream.. Odd. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Arhimed, did you know how can I test if the RAM memory is full in every save of file. I don't want that the application closed

Comment: Check the `net.rim.device.api.system.Memory` for details. However I believe if RAM shortage is the issue, then you should have got an `OutOfMemoryException` (which is not the case).